# combine list of list element in python

Tags: python, python-2.5

Let say I have the a list of list

```
[ ['B','2'] , ['o','0'], ['y']]
```

and I want to combine the list into something like this without using iteratool

```
["Boy","B0y","2oy","20y"]
```

I can't use itertool because I have to use python 2.5.

Comment: If you don't want to use itertools look at the python code equivalent of the itertools function and either Copy&Paste it (bad!) or re-implement it (also bad, it'll be slower!). -1 for adding a requirement that makes no sense without explaining the reason.

Comment: _"im have to use python 2.5"_ - \*tags as python-2.7\*

Comment: [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html): _"New in version **2.3**."_. Although [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) does what you want.

```
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(*[['B', '2'], ['o', '0'], ['y']])]
['Boy', 'B0y', '2oy', '20y']
```

Comment: what if i cant use the iteratool

Comment: Then you please explain why that's the case. Or you just click the link in my answer and copy&paste the `itertools.product` implementation and use that one....

Comment: i want to know is there other way to do this without using itertool also. I know that can be implement just using itertools

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use itertools, this list comprehension produces your output:

```
>>> LoL=[['B','2'], ['o','0'], ['y']]
>>> [a+b+c for a in LoL[0] for b in LoL[1] for c in LoL[2]]
['Boy', 'B0y', '2oy', '20y']
```

This is a more compact version of this:

```
LoL=[['B','2'], ['o','0'], ['y']]
r=[]
for a in LoL[0]:
    for b in LoL[1]:
        for c in LoL[2]:
            r.append(a+b+c)

print r
```

In either case, you are producing a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) which is better and more flexibly done with [itertools.product()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) (unless you are just curious about how to do it...)